# How should I handle Error Messages in a Library, For a Display Only Application

Tags: c#

I have a library with several layers. The library is a hardware API and has several threads. The application that is using it has no direct user interaction the UI is for display only. I needed a way to tell the user if there was an error and what it was. So I created an Error Event that passes a message up the layers.

This does not seem like a direct violation of separation of concerns, though maybe a gray area.

The library is supposed to recover from most errors on its own. For example: if it loses connection to the hardware it just keeps trying to reconnect, when it does it can continue.

I needed a way to clear the error message off the screen once the error was cleared, so I created a ClearErrorMessage Event that is fired once the library continues. This tells the UI to clear the error message off the screen.

My ClearErrorMessage event seems to be a clear violation of separation of concerns since the library should not care about what is above it.

Is there a better way to handle this that is more modular in nature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I donot see a "separation of concerns" problem if your lib creates an event `onHardwareStatusChanged(String currentStatusMessage)` where your display-only applicaton can register for.

the display application might display "connection to host http:... lost" and a few minutes later "everything is ok".

Answer (score 2):

> I needed a way to clear the error message off the screen

Here's your concern. The application needs a way to clear error messages, not your library. Your library should communicate about the state, the application should decide what to do with it.

I like doing that with registering an event, but you can also let the application poll your API for the current state.